# How to set the width of the exponent field for an ostream?

Tags: c++

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main( int, char **argv )
{
std::cout << 1.23e45 << std::endl;
}
```

prints

> 1.23e+045

when compiled with MS Visual Studio 2003, and

> 1.23e+45

on my Linux machine.

How can I specify the width of the exponent field (and why is there a difference in the first place)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with standard manipulators. (if it is, I'd love to be corrected and learn how)

Your only remaining option is creating a streambuf yourself, and intercepting all exponent numbers that go to the stream, reformat them by hand, and pass them on to the underlying stream.

Seems a lot of work, and while not rocket science, no trivial task either.

On the 'why' question: I know linux defines the exponent as minimum two digits, I suppose Windows specifies it as minimum three?

```
// on linux
std::cout << std::scientific << 1.23e4 << std::endl
```

Also adds a leading zero:

```
1.230000e+04
```

Comment: You can also calculate mantissa and exponent by hand as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29582919/find-exponent-and-mantissa-of-a-double-to-the-base-10#comment47314287_29582919), and then use `sprintf` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up of @Pieter's answer, I've been looking inside the operator<< (ostream&, double).  Indeed, there is no field to specify the significance or width of the exponent.  On windows, the operator<< forwards to sprintf, which has no exponent-size either.

In it's turn, the sprintf function (on Windows) calls into _cfltcvt_l, a function we have no source code for, but whose signature doesn't provide for an exponent-precision.

I know nothing of the implementation on Linux.

Answer (score -1):

Look into the iomanip header.  It has a lot of width-precision etc... functionality.

Comment: Which one do I need? the width is the full width, the precision is the number of digits of the mantissa.

Comment: as far as I know it's not possible with default iomanip attributes, as you said, both precision and width do something else...

Comment: @Pieter: I propose you file that as an Answer, although it is not the answer that I was hoping for =-(